# Implementation of two ListViews in a Frame Layout

Tags: android, listview, zooming, android-framelayout

i have very basic knowledge about the framelayout . i wants to implement two listviews in a One frame Layout plus and the condition is  whenever i click any of list out of two list in a frame layout "the clicked list  must get zoomed out to fill the screen".

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to do this, if you've read the [FrameLayout doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) you'd see this:

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other. You can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each child, using the android:layout_gravity attribute.

What you want to use is [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

I hope this helps.

Comment: yes it just skip my mind , then i need to use two fragments? so will i be able to make list zoomed out after a click , can you give any example i studied the sample example of frame layout but i was unable to understand it

Comment: @Abhi I think 2 fragments will work best for you. No example comes to mind right now. I suggest starting to implement it little by little and solving problems as you implement it.